# Как правильно перегрузить оператор []?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Задача перегрузить бинарные и унарные операции. Начал с операции []. Проблема в том, что я так и не понял является вариант перегрузки снизу правильным. Можете сказать правильно или нет, если неправильно, то пояснить почему?

```
void  operator[](int index){
    if (index>count || index<0 ){
        cout<<endl<<"Неправильный индекс!";
    }
    else
    {
        print_choose(index);
    }
```

Функция print_choose()

```
void print_choose(int pos){
    if(pos == 0) print_head();
    if(pos == count) print_tail();
    int i = 0;
    ClassOne* temp =Head;
    if(pos<count && pos!=0){
        while(i<pos){
            temp=temp->next;
            i++;
        }
        cout<<"============================================"<<endl;
        cout << "str1: " << temp->str1 << endl;
        cout << "str2: " << temp->str2<< endl;
        cout << "str3: " << temp->str3 << endl;
        cout << "str4: " << temp->str4 << endl;
        cout << "str5: " << temp->str5<< endl;
        cout << "str6: " << temp->str6<< endl;
        cout << "str7: " << temp->str7 << endl;
        cout<<"============================================"<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Где остальной контекст? Не говоря уже о том, что оператор `[]`, занимающийся вводом-выводом выглядит, мягко говоря, странно.

Comment: Не стоит подменять семантику другой - не говорю о других, кто ваш код читать будет, но вы сами запутаетесь. Иными словами - переопределенный оператор + не должен, например, вычитать, оператор ^ возводить в степень... ну, а оператор [] заниматься выводом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как то так перегружается проверка на валидность индекса на усмотрение но в том же векторе он не проверяется там есть метод at

```
T& operator[](int index){
   return T[index];
}

const T& operator[](int index) const {
   return T[index];
}
```